# What causes Kubernetes to create multiple container of same image in a pod?

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, containers, amazon-eks

We have a Spring Boot application that processes Kafka messages.  The application is run under Kubernetes using Amazon EKS.  The arrival of messages is very bursty, so KEDA is used to scale from 0 to 80 instances as needed.

Now the problem.  On rare occasions we are finding the logs (DataDog) two instances of the application starting and running in a single pod.  This is confirmed as each instance has a different container_id.  When this occurs the Kafka Consumer in each instance is processing the same message which cause failures further on down the line.

Has anyone come across this, or have an idea what might be causing the problem?  At this point I am not even sure where to start looking.